# check if input value exits as an option in a select

Tags: jquery

I'm making a form for adding a new option to a select. But I need to make sure that it doesn't exist already. I know there's 'inArray' function in Jquery, I'm just at a loss as to how to apply it to select options.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to test for existance based on the value attribute, you can do something like this:

```
var optVal = "some value";

if ($('#yourSelectElement > option[value="' + optVal + '"]').length === 0) {
   // doesn't exist so add here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check and see if an option exists that already has your new options value.

```
var newOptionVal = 'foo';
if ($('option[value='+newOptionVal+']').length > 0) {
    //option already exists
}
```

Comment: Your code only works if you select the option that is the same as the value of the input. @nnnnnn got it right. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah I thought you would realize you can use an else or place a ! Operator at the start. Glad your up and running.